# Can apex:outputLabel render images?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a bunch of columns that are in repeat tags.  I'm rendering them by iterating through a list in visualforce. For one of the columns I have a value of Y or blank, and in the case of Y I want to render an image stored as a static resouce. Can I do that by still using the tags?

```
            <apex:repeat value="{!metaDataList}" var="element">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">{!element['fieldName']}</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!item[element['sFieldName']]}"/>
            </apex:column>
            </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
<apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">{!element['fieldName']}</apex:facet>
    <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.RESOURCENAME)}" rendered="{!item[element['sFieldName']] = 'Y'}"/>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Can I do it still with an output label tag instead of using the image tag? The reason why is that this column is in the in the middle of the page, and I'd need to break up stuff

Comment: Wrap it in a span or something. I do not believe that you can output an image with an output label . But you can wrap it in other mage or apply css to put it where you want it